# WP7 - IsTrial() method - always returning false (SIDELOADED and PRODUCTION)

Tags: windows-phone-7

Am I doing something incorrectly with this?

My app went out last night, but I noticed that my code for the free trial wasn't firing.  This method is being called and it always returning **FALSE (Full Mode)**.

What am I doing wrong?  Right now my app is free :(

```
    private static Boolean IsTrial()
    {
        #if DEBUG
            return false;
        #endif

        var license = new Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation();
        return license.IsTrial();
    }
```

Currently I have this app sideloaded on my machine.  I am updating my pivot header and setting the status for the various checks I have.  Right now in the SIDELOADED version it always returns false.

I downloaded my app from the MarketPlace last night (as a Free Trial).  The production version is always returning False and so is the Sideloaded version.

Any ideas?

This is my calling code (just in case anyone is interested):

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    pivotPills.Title = "PillBox v1.2 - Checking Mode:";
    App.ViewModel.RefreshTrialMode();
    pivotPills.Title = "PillBox v1.2 - Count:" + App.ViewModel.trialItemCollection.Count.ToString();
    //Checking Trial Mode:
    if (App.ViewModel.trialItemCollection.Count == 0)
    {
        trialMode tm = new trialMode();
        tm.IsTrial = true;
        tm.Save();
        pivotPills.Title = "PillBox v1.2 - Trial Mode:" + App.ViewModel.trialItemCollection.Count.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (App.ViewModel.trialItemCollection[0].IsTrial == true) //If saved isTrial = true (still a trial) then check MarketPlace Task
        {
            if (IsTrial() == false) //Purchased App
            {
                App.ViewModel.trialItemCollection[0].IsTrial = false;
                StorageHelper.Save<ObservableCollection<trialMode>>(App.trialModeData, App.ViewModel.trialItemCollection);
                pivotPills.Title = "PillBox v1.2 - Unlimited";
            }
            else //Still in Trial Mode
            {
                //show marketplace window
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MarketPlace.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IsTrial` method always returns false when you are running in the emulator (which I presume is the case for you). Check out the [How to: Test and Debug Your Trial Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967557%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) article on MSDN for help debugging trial applications.

Comment: Does it do this even when the app is side loaded? I had the #DEBUG hash code in the emulator (and specifically I used the link you provided)... Now I'm side loading it and the app has been released and I downloaded it from the MarketPlace (as a free trial). When ever I call this code it returns False (again side loaded and the version that I downloaded from the MP).  So something in my call isn't right...

Comment: If `IsTrial` is giving you false for an application downloaded from the Marketplace, then as far as the framework is concerned the application does not have a trial. If you submitted your application and specified that it has a trial, then you should contact Microsoft to correct this. Whether or not an application is in trial mode is outside of the developer's control.

Comment: According to this: http://wp7applist.com/app/7500/Pill+Box - Trial available  YES....  I have a feeling it is probably my issue more than MS ;)  I wish it were the other way around.

Comment: As Matt suggested, it may well be a problem with the DEBUG directive, then.

Comment: @Jeff V: You can download the trial version of your app from the marketplace (don't worry about it wiping any existing data you have in your sideloaded app, the phone will see the 2 as 2 separate apps). The downloaded trial version should show whatever trial mode behavior your app is supposed to exhibit. I was stumped by this for a little while too until I just downloaded the trial onto my phone.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the version you submitted didn't contain the DEBUG directive?

Also the version in the Marketplace is version 1.0, but your code seems to think it's version 1.2. Is it just that the code your looking at doesn't match what's compiled/released?

*Also your app crashes when I try and press the back button when selecting a contact.* :(

Comment: @Matt - the 1.2 is on my dev machine that I'm trying to figure this out...  The 1.0 version might of have the #Debug directive in it...  I thought I commented it out but now I don't remember...  Also what do you mean when you select a contact (Doctor, Pharmacy or something different)?  I also read that even sideloaded isTrial will return false.  Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: @Jeff what do you mean by "sideloaded"? IsTrial will only ever work on an app if it's come from the Marketplace.

Comment: @Jeff Crashes when I double tap on the phone symbol next "Doctor Number" on "Pill Details" pivot and various other points when you are using Choosers.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks!  I'll update this question after 1.2 gets released.